# Will a new iOS in-app purchase submitted with a new app version be available in previous app versions?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I am currently working on an iOS project with in-app purchases implemented. The current implementation is as follows:

- Product IDs and other meta-data for in-app purchases are hosted on a remote server.
- App requests this data from server, then performs SKProductRequest with Product IDs from server.
- Product IDs returned as valid from SKProductRequest are displayed to user.

I want to submit a new app bundle with some additional in-app purchases that only work in the new version and are ignored by the previous versions.

So my question is, if I submit a new app bundle along with some new in-app purchases will the SKProductRequest in the previous app version return the new in-app purchase identifiers as valid?

Will I have to create a way for the server to only return the new in-app purchases if requested from the new bundle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question shouldn't come up.  You request the product list and you supply the identifiers using something like

```
 [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers: prodset];
```

and then set the delegate and start.  In the prodset, you have a list of identifiers for products of interest.  Your older app versions should neither have nor supply the identifiers for products that aren't relevant.  If you download the product list from another source (your server), then it can and should filter based on version.

Answer (score 1):

I've approached this by including a minimum version number in my list of product meta data.  If the IAP minimum version is later than the user's version, then a popup suggests to the user that they should upgrade so they can get access to the new features.